# An app is not running

Tags: android

I am trying to run an app, but following exception is encountered and the app isn't running

ActivityManager: android.util.AndroidException: Can't connect to activity manager; is the system running?

All other apps are running which means there is no problem in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout in DDMS, Can you see your emulator in 'Devices' window. 
If not, restart the emulator. Before running application, devices window should have a device selected.